# Entity Framework "An error occurred while executing the command definition"

Tags: entity-framework

I have spent ages trying solution to no avail, so please help.
I have a table on the database as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FlowsortJobDetails](
[JobID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[SortID] [varchar](11) NOT NULL,
[SortType] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
[SortStatus] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
[JobName] [varchar](16) NULL,
[Year] [varchar](4) NULL,
[Sight] [varchar](2) NULL,
[Lot] [varchar](16) NULL,
[JobSize] [varchar](16) NULL,
[JobWeight] [float] NULL,
[SaveAllImages] [bit] NULL,
[SortmapFilename] [varchar](32) NULL,
[BinAllocationFilename] [varchar](32) NULL,
[SplitFilename] [varchar](32) NULL,
[AllToBinNumber] [int] NULL,
[NumberOfWays] [int] NULL,
[CreatedBy] [varchar](16) NULL,
[CreatedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[StartedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[MachineID] [varchar](8) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have an entity interface as:

public DbSet FlowsortJobDetails { get; set; }

and a data definition as:

```
[Table("FlowsortJobDetails")]
public class Job
{
    public System.Int32 JobID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(11)]
    public System.String SortID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(16)]
    public System.String SortType { get; set; }
    [StringLength(8)]
    public System.String SortStatus { get; set; }
    [StringLength(16)]
    public System.String JobName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(4)]
    public System.String Year { get; set; }
    [StringLength(2)]
    public System.String Sight { get; set; }
    [StringLength(16)]
    public System.String Lot { get; set; }
    [StringLength(16)]
    public System.String JobSize { get; set; }
    public System.Double JobWeight { get; set; }
    public System.Boolean SaveAllImages { get; set; }
    [StringLength(32)]
    public System.String SortmapFilename { get; set; }
    [StringLength(32)]
    public System.String BinAllocationFilename { get; set; }
    [StringLength(32)]
    public System.String SplitFilename { get; set; }
    public System.Int32 AllToBinNumber { get; set; }
    public System.Int32 NumberOfWays { get; set; }
    [StringLength(16)]
    public System.String CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartedDate { get; set; }
    [StringLength(8)]
    public System.String MachineID { get; set; }
}
```

I can read this table from the database using SqlDataAdapter to confirm the data names and definitions. I would like to use the Entity Framework to read and update this table, but all I get is an Exception telling me "Invalid column name .." from JobName onwards.

Comment: Shouldn't `public DbSet FlowsortJobDetails { get; set; }` be `public DbSet<Job> FlowsortJobDetails { get; set; }` ?

Comment: Sorry, there must have been something wrong with the cut and paste as this is actually what I have in my code.

Comment: Have you tried to add the `[Key]` attribute on JobId?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have now tried this but still get the same result.